# Gulp with Angular 2 Environment variable

Tags: typescript, gulp, angular

How to pass a parameter Angular-2 script using Gulp? In order to Angular-2 could get the value of this variable at startup.
To start gulp was about: `gulp start --type=dev` and that the Angulyar-2 could get the value of the variable "type"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on which tool you are using to **compile** TypeScript.

Use DefinePlugin if you are compiling with gulp-webpack or webpack-stream, it does exactly what you want.

If you are using gulp plugins like gulp-typescript, gulp-ts or gulp-typescript-compiler then you could emulate variable injection using [gulp-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace) or [gulp-preprocess](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-preprocess). Also check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164019/how-to-inject-variable-value-into-js-file-from-gulp), you could generate TypeScript config in similar manner.

Declare global var (add *.d.ts file if necessary):

```
export interface IConfig {param:boolean}
declare var config:IConfig;
```

In you gulp task:

```
var config = {};
if(process.argv.indexOf('--name') > -1){
    config.param = true;
}
else {
    config.param = false;
}

fs.writeFileSync('path../config.js', 'var config='+JSON.stringify(config));
```

Import `config.js` using `<script>` tag.

Comment: I use simple ts2js

Comment: It looks like ts2js does not follow gulp way (stream, pipes). Is fairly simple to setup one of gulp-typescript, gulp-ts or gulp-typescript-compiler plugins.

Comment: I would like to continue to use ts2js.. without other plugin-compiler

Comment: i guess the only option is to generate config.ts dynamically.

Comment: can be an example please?