# Pass variable from gulp to JS file

Tags: javascript, gulp

I want to pass `process.ENV.TEST` variable that is accessible in `gulpfile.js` to the local file I am using (and which I include in `index.html`). How can I do that?

```
server.use(express.static('./app'));
server.listen(SERVER_PORT);
```

I want to pass this variable to one of the files within the `./app` directory - is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to inject variable value into JS file from GULP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164019/how-to-inject-variable-value-into-js-file-from-gulp)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [yargs](https://github.com/yargs/yargs) npm plugin, to accept arguments

```
// install --save-dev yargs

var yargs = require('yargs');

//To access use
yargs.argumentName
```